# Error in my vb but correct in my sql query

Tags: vb.net

Error in my vb but correct in my sql query. Can somebody can correct my VB code.

This is my wrong code in VB

```
cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM tblvendorpartnumber WHERE vendorpnumber ='" & Trim(TextBox11.Text.TrimEnd()) & " OR vendorpnumber ='" & Trim(TextBox2.Text.TrimEnd()) & "'", con)
```

This is my correct code in mysql query

```
SELECT *
FROM pcba_info.tblvendorpartnumber
WHERE partnumber = '' or vendorpnumber = '';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must resolved the problem in SQL injections to

You forgot to include the pair of other single quote.

From

```
TextBox11.Text.TrimEnd()) & " OR
```

To

```
Trim(TextBox11.Text.TrimEnd()) & "' OR
```

To form as

```
cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM tblvendorpartnumber WHERE vendorpnumber ='" & TextBox11.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''") & "' OR vendorpnumber ='" & TextBox2.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''") & "'", con)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid mixing the VB string functions with those of SQL. Write the entire query inside quotes to be certain will work in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Trim will trim any leading or trailing blank spaces from a string. So if the string was " Text", then Trim would delete those spaces for you, leaving just "Text".

```
Dim S1,S2  as String
S1 = TextBox11.Text
S2 = TextBox12.Text
cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM tblvendorpartnumber WHERE vendorpnumber ='" & S1.Trim & " OR vendorpnumber ='" & S2.Trim & "'", con)
```